CRITICAL Clock : Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame
I created CustomCard for displaying data in sqlite. The problem i encounter is when there are atleast 20 CustomCards created, it shows the error based on the title.

[CRITICAL] [Clock       ] Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame. Check your code, or increase the Clock.max_iteration attribute. Remaining events:
<ClockEvent (-1.0) callback=<bound method Label.texture_update of <main.AdaptiveLabel object at 0x000001994A383680>>>
<ClockEvent (-1.0) callback=<bound method BoxLayout.do_layout of <kivymd.uix.boxlayout.MDBoxLayout object at 0x000001994A317610>>>
**

This only happens when i used RecycleView. Before I was just using a loop of MDCards but the performance is degrading and i need atleast 100 cards to create so switching to RecycleView is important
Here is the minimal code:
class AdaptiveLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint_y = None
        self.bind(texture_size=self.update_height)
        self.bind(width=self.update_text_size)

    def update_height(self, *args):
        self.height = self.texture_size[1]

    def update_text_size(self, *args):
        self.text_size = (self.width, None)


class CustomCard(BoxLayout, RecycleDataViewBehavior):
    bg_color = ListProperty([1, 1, 1, 1])
    event_id = NumericProperty()
    widget_count = NumericProperty()
    event_type = StringProperty()
    reference_number = StringProperty()
    remarks = StringProperty()
    image_count = NumericProperty()
    latitude = NumericProperty()
    longitude = NumericProperty()
    image_path = StringProperty(defaultvalue='')
    index = None


    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        self.index = index
        self.event_id = int(data.get('event_id', 0))
        self.widget_count = data.get('widget_count', 0)
        self.event_type = data.get('event_type', '')
        self.reference_number = data.get('reference_number', '')
        self.remarks = data.get('remarks', '')
        self.image_count = data.get('image_count', 0)
        self.latitude = data.get('latitude', 0)
        self.longitude = data.get('longitude', 0)
        self.image_path = data.get('image_path', '')

        return super(CustomCard, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.on_release()
            return True
        return super(CustomCard, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_release(self):
        app = MDApp.get_running_app()
        print(f"Event ID on release: {self.event_id}")
        app.display_event_details(self.event_id)

class MainFunction(MDApp):
     def fetch_data_from_db(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('event.db')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            'SELECT event_id, event_type, reference_number, remarks, image_path, image_count, latitude,longitude FROM events')
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        print(data)
        conn.close()
        return data

    # Main Add widgets

    def add_main_widgets(self):
        def fetch_data_thread():
            events_data = self.fetch_data_from_db()
            # Once data is fetched, update the UI on the main thread
            Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.update_ui_with_data(events_data), 0)

        Thread(target=fetch_data_thread).start()

    def update_ui_with_data(self, events_data):
        event_buttons = self.sm.get_screen('main').ids.bottom_nav
        card_list = self.sm.get_screen('main').ids.card_list
        current_data = {card['event_id']: card for card in card_list.data}

        for event in events_data:
            event_id, event_type, reference_number, remarks, image_path, image_count, latitude, longitude = event

            if event_id in self.cards_dict:
                # Update existing card
                card_data = self.cards_dict[event_id]
                card_data['event_type'] = event_type
                card_data['reference_number'] = reference_number
                card_data['remarks'] = remarks
                card_data['image_count'] = image_count
                card_data['latitude'] = latitude
                card_data['longitude'] = longitude
            else:

                card_data = {
                    'event_id': event_id,
                    'widget_count': len(self.cards_dict) + 1,
                    'event_type': event_type,
                    'reference_number': reference_number,
                    'remarks': remarks,
                    'image_count': image_count,
                    'latitude': latitude,
                    'longitude': longitude
                }
                self.cards_dict[event_id] = card_data
                card_list.data.append(card_data)

        event_buttons.action_items = [
            MDActionBottomAppBarButton(icon="send-circle"),
            MDActionBottomAppBarButton(icon="image"),
        ]

        # Force a refresh
        card_list.refresh_from_data()

And here is my kv file:
<CustomCard>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    padding: "5dp"
    spacing: "10sp"
    radius: 16

    MDFloatLayout:
        size_hint: .01, .95
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .02, "center_y": .5}
        md_bg_color: "yellow" if root.latitude and root.longitude else "#EC1F26"

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        AdaptiveLabel:
            text: f"[{root.widget_count} of {root.widget_count}]: {root.reference_number}"
            font_size:"15sp"
            color:"black"
            bold: True

        AdaptiveLabel:
            text: "Remarks:"
            bold: True
            font_size:"13sp"
            color:"#666666"
            height: self.texture_size[1] if root.remarks else 0
            opacity: 1 if root.remarks else 0
        AdaptiveLabel:
            text: root.remarks
            font_size:"12sp"
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
            height: self.texture_size[1] if root.remarks else 0
            opacity: 1 if root.remarks else 0

        MDButton:
            style: 'text'
            height: "20dp" if root.image_count > 0 else 0
            size_hint_x: .3
            opacity: 1 if root.image_count > 0 else 0
            MDButtonIcon:
                icon: 'image'
                x: 1
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                icon_color: "black"
            MDButtonText:
                text: f"{root.image_count} Pictures"
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: "black"

        AdaptiveLabel:
            text: "Status: Ready to transmit" if root.latitude and root.longitude else "Status: No location found"
            bold: True
            font_size: "12sp"
            color: "#666666"

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'right'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 120, 50
        pos_hint: {'right': 1, 'top': 1}
        AdaptiveLabel:
            text: root.event_type
            font_name: "f2icons/status.ttf"
            halign: "right"
            color: "#ffff00"
            font_size: "16sp"


<AdaptiveLabel>
MDScreen:
    name: 'main'
    md_bg_color: "#ffffff"
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True
        size_hint_y: .83
        RecycleView:
            id: card_list
            viewclass: "CustomCard"
            RecycleGridLayout:
                default_size: None, dp(120)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                spacing: dp(10)
                padding: dp(10)
                cols: 1  # Ensure single column layout

I knew it was on the CustomCard widgets but i can not find the exact solution here.
Also the UI has also bug. The height does not adjusting automatically even though it is. Photo for reference


If you schedule a callback that schedules a callback that schedules a … etc more than 10 times, it will leave the loop and send a warning to the console, then continue after the next frame. This is implemented to prevent bugs from hanging or crashing the application.
However, Clock has an iteration limit for these callbacks: it defaults to 10.
If you need to increase the iteration limit, just add this to main.py file;
from kivy.clock import Clock

Clock.max_iteration=30 #increase the limit if it still gives warning.


That works! Thank you so much
